# Cannot input text into the textbox, I'm able to click on it but cannot add text to it via send_keys()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnniJ.png)

I have included the code in the picture due to formatting issues.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5manx617hq0u2hc/texbox.png?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You are unlikely to get much help by including pictures of code. You should include the code within your question directly.  Please take the time to read about how to format a good question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that code:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.netacad.com/portal/saml_login")
time.sleep(3)
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input--dirty input--valid inputDom']")
el.send_keys("you email")
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```